# String Search C program without using built-in functions

Tags: c

I have a problem in my C program. This is the String Search program. The problem is when I type the String `aabaaacaamaad`, the result comes `NULL` when I search for `ab` in it but it should not as `ab` is there in `aabaaacaamaad`. The same result also comes with `am` and `ad` which is right but why does it come with `aabaaacaamaad`? Code:

```
char* MyStrstr(char* pszSearchString, char* pszSearchWord);
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char szTemp1[20] = {0};
    char szTemp2[10] = {0};
    char * pszTemp1 = NULL;
    strcpy(szTemp1, "aabaaacaamaad");
    strcpy(szTemp2, "aa");

    pszTemp1 = MyStrstr(szTemp1, szTemp2);
    printf("%s", pszTemp1);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

char* MyStrstr(char* pszSearchString, char* pszSearchWord) 
{
    int nFcount = 0;                    
    int nScount = 0;                    
    int nSearchLen = 0;
    int nIndex = 0;
    char* pszDelString = NULL; 

    if(pszSearchString == NULL || pszSearchWord == NULL) {
    return NULL;
    }   

    while(pszSearchWord[nSearchLen] != '\0') {
        nSearchLen++;
    }                       
    if(nSearchLen <= 0){
        return pszSearchString;
    }

    for(nFcount = 0; pszSearchString[nFcount] != '\0'; nFcount++) {
        if(pszSearchString[nFcount] == pszSearchWord[nScount]) {
           nScount++;
        } else {
           nScount = 0;
        }  

        if(nScount == nSearchLen) {
            nIndex = (nFcount - nScount) + 1;
            pszDelString = pszSearchString + nIndex;
            return pszDelString;
        }
   }
   return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Please read [this blog post](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You could try adding some debug printfs and check where exactly is NULL getting returned

Comment: I know why NULL is returned. In the String I typed in the program, 'aab' and 'aad' have exceptions. These are the places where the program was wrong. I don't know how to handle this places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what your code is trying to do, you want to avoid a loop in a loop but however you're missing one thing. When a match fails you're not going back but still moving forward in `pszSearchString` while you should not. The result of this flaw is that with incomplete matches you skip characters.  That's the reason why the strstr function originally uses a loop in a loop so for every character in `pszSearchString` there is an new loop to match with `pszSearchWord`. Here the original strstr.c file from BSD/Darwin:

```
char * strstr(const char *in, const char *str)
{
    char c;
    size_t len;

    c = *str++;
    if (!c)
        return (char *) in; // Trivial empty string case

    len = strlen(str);
    do {
        char sc;

        do {
            sc = *in++;
            if (!sc)
                return (char *) 0;
        } while (sc != c);
    } while (strncmp(in, str, len) != 0);

    return (char *) (in - 1);
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't work with command prompt. I also want to work with command prompt so, how can I change this code for command prompt? Please give me an advice. With regards...

Comment: You can copy paste the code next to the main function and call it from there. pass argv[1] and argv[2] (argument 1 and 2 from the command line) to the function. Then the only thing you'll need to do is compare the pointers and print and return the right values.